# How to embed Image inline in new Wordpress post using API

Tags: vba, wordpress-rest-api

I am building a VBA app that uses the Wordpress API to create legislator pages from the GovTrack website. The app should loop over all the legislators shown at https://www.govtrack.us/congress/members/current and create one page for each legislator that shows his or her photo and the description from GovTrack. After many hours of research and experimentation, I can do most of this but placement of media inside content is proving troublesome.

So far the process goes like this. First I add the photo to the media library and retrieve the ID of the new media item from the response. Then I create the page using the description of the legislator from GovTrack as content and I specify the ID of the photo as the featured_media of the JSON requestBody if the HTTP request that creates the new page.

Here is the code to add the keys and items to the dictionary that provide content and media for the new page, where pageContent is a string that comes from GovTrack and mediaID is the Wordpress ID number for the media.

```
jsonDict.Add key:="content", Item:=pageContent
jsonDict.Add key:="featured_media", Item:=mediaID
```

The code using these parameters works but the resulting new page shows the media in the header of my theme and not in the body of the content. Obviously this is the default placement but there must be a way to specify the placement of media somewhere else, i.e., inline with the content of a post or a page but it is entirely unclear from any documentation I can find so far, how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.